# Move Cursor Line Position QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6

- Text editor: Sublime Text 3
- Python Version: 3.6
- UTF-8
- PyQt5

I am making a notepad in PyQt5 and I am making an option to be able to navigate between the lines and, of course, I need to move the text editor cursor so that it is in the line that the user wants, and the problem is that, nose how to move the cursor of a TextEdit. I have used several methods and none works. Simply or does not move the cursor or an error jumps.

This is the full code: https://github.com/MasPot4/Bloc-de-Notas

This is the part of the error

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QTextEdit, QMessageBox, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QMenu, QAction, QFileDialog, QLineEdit
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()

class textEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(textEdit, self).__init__()

        self.cursor = self.textCursor()

class gotolineWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(gotolineWin, self).__init__()
        self.main = textEdit()
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.go_line = QLineEdit(self)
        self.buttonGoto = QPushButton("Go to...", self)
        self.buttonCancel = QPushButton("Cancel", self)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.label.setText("Go to...")
        self.label.move(20, 0)

        self.go_line.move(20, 25)
        self.go_line.resize(260, 20)

        self.buttonGoto.move(20, 60)
        self.buttonGoto.resize(100, 30)
        self.buttonGoto.clicked.connect(lambda: self.GoToLine(int(self.go_line.text())))

        self.buttonCancel.clicked.connect(self.cancel)
        self.buttonCancel.move(180, 60)

        self.setGeometry((width / 2) - 150, (height / 2) - 50, 300, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle("Go to...")

    def GoToLine(self, line):
        # self.main.cursor = self.main.textCursor()
        # self.main.cursor.movePosition(self.main.cursor.Left, self.main.cursor.KeepAnchor, 3)
        # self.main.setTextCursor(self.main.cursor)

        ln = int(line)
        linecursor = QTextCursor(self.main.document().findBlockByLineNumber(ln - 1))
        self.main.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
        self.main.setTextCursor(linecursor)

        self.close()

    def cancel(self):
        self.close()

class writter(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.textEdit = textEdit()
        self.lineWin = gotolineWin()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)

        self.file_name = None

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('File')
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu('Edit')
        formatMenu = menubar.addMenu('Format')
        viewMenu = menubar.addMenu("View")

        # File Menu     
        new_file = QAction('New', self)
        new_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        new_file.triggered.connect(self.newfile)

        open_file = QAction('Open...', self)
        open_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        open_file.triggered.connect(self.openfile)

        save_file = QAction('Save', self)
        save_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        save_file.triggered.connect(self.savefile)

        save_as_file = QAction('Save As...', self)
        save_as_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+S")
        save_as_file.triggered.connect(self.saveasfile)

        exit = QAction("Exit", self)
        exit.triggered.connect(self.quit)

        # Edit Menu
        undo_edit = QAction("Undo", self)
        undo_edit.setShortcut("Ctrl+Z")
        undo_edit.triggered.connect(self.undo)

        cut_edit = QAction("Cut", self)
        cut_edit.setShortcut("Ctrl+X")
        cut_edit.triggered.connect(self.cut)

        copy_edit = QAction("Copy", self)
        copy_edit.setShortcut("Ctrl+C")
        copy_edit.triggered.connect(self.copy)

        paste_edit = QAction("Paste", self)
        paste_edit.setShortcut("Ctrl+V")
        paste_edit.triggered.connect(self.paste)

        delete_edit = QAction("Delete", self)
        delete_edit.setShortcut("Supr")
        delete_edit.triggered.connect(self.delete)

        goto_edit = QAction("Go To...", self)
        goto_edit.setShortcut("Ctrl+T")
        goto_edit.triggered.connect(self.gotoline)

        find_editor = QAction("Find", self)
        find_editor.setShortcut("Ctrl+F")

        select_all_edit = QAction("Select All", self)
        select_all_edit.setShortcut("Ctrl+E")

        time_edit = QAction("Date and Time", self)
        time_edit.setShortcut("F5")

        # Format Menu
        font_format = QAction("Font", self)

        # View Menu
        zoom_view = QMenu("Zoom", self)
        zoom_mas_view = QAction("Zoom In", self)
        zoom_mas_view.setShortcut("Ctrl++")
        zoom_menos_view = QAction("Ward Off", self)
        zoom_menos_view.setShortcut("Ctrl+-")
        zoom_pre_view = QAction("Restore Default Zoom", self)
        zoom_pre_view.setShortcut("Ctrl+0")
        zoom_view.addAction(zoom_mas_view)
        zoom_view.addAction(zoom_menos_view)
        zoom_view.addAction(zoom_pre_view)

        statusbar_view = QAction("Status Bar", self)

        fileMenu.addAction(new_file)
        fileMenu.addAction(open_file)
        fileMenu.addAction(save_file)
        fileMenu.addAction(save_as_file)
        fileMenu.addSeparator()
        fileMenu.addAction(exit)

        editMenu.addAction(undo_edit)
        editMenu.addSeparator()
        editMenu.addAction(cut_edit)
        editMenu.addAction(copy_edit)
        editMenu.addAction(paste_edit)
        editMenu.addAction(delete_edit)
        editMenu.addSeparator()
        editMenu.addAction(goto_edit)
        editMenu.addAction(find_editor)
        editMenu.addSeparator()
        editMenu.addAction(select_all_edit)
        editMenu.addAction(time_edit)

        viewMenu.addMenu(zoom_view)
        viewMenu.addAction(statusbar_view)

        self.setGeometry((width / 2) - 300, (height / 2) - 250, 600, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("NotePad 2.0")
        self.show()

    def newfile(self):
        if self.textEdit.toPlainText() != "":
            buttonReply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Bloc de Notas 2.0', f"You want to save changes to Sin Titulo?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
            if buttonReply == QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.saveasfile()
            else:
                try:
                    name, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "New File", "New File.txt", "All Files (*.*)")
                    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(name)
                    name = url.fileName()
                    with open(name, "w") as f:
                        f.write("")
                    self.textEdit.clear()
                    self.file_name = name
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    pass
        else:
            try:
                name, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "New File", "New File.txt", "All Files (*.*)")
                url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(name)
                name = url.fileName()
                with open(name, "w") as f:
                    f.write("")
                self.textEdit.clear()
                self.file_name = name
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

    def openfile(self):
        if self.textEdit.toPlainText() != "":
            buttonReply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Bloc de Notas 2.0', f"You want to save changes to Sin Titulo?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
            if buttonReply == QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.saveasfile()               
            else:
                try:
                    name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "New File", "New File.txt", "All Files (*.*)")
                    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(name)
                    name = url.fileName()
                    with open(name, "r") as f:
                        content = f.read()
                    self.textEdit.setText(content)
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    pass
        else:
            try:
                name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "New File", "New File.txt", "All Files (*.*)")
                url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(name)
                name = url.fileName()
                with open(name, "r") as f:
                    content = f.read()
                self.textEdit.setText(content)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

    def savefile(self):
        if self.textEdit.toPlainText() == "":
            self.newfile()
        elif self.textEdit.toPlainText() != "":
            if self.file_name == None:
                self.saveasfile()
            else:
                with open(self.file_name, "w") as f:
                    f.write(self.textEdit.toPlainText())
        elif self.file_name == None:
            self.saveasfile()

    def saveasfile(self):
        try:
            name, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,'Save File', "New File.txt", "All Files (*.*)")
            with open(name, "w") as f:
                f.write(self.textEdit.toPlainText())
            self.file_name = name
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    def quit(self):
        sys.exit()

    def undo(self):
        self.textEdit.undo()

    def cut(self):
        self.textEdit.copy()
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText("")

    def copy(self):
        self.textEdit.copy()

    def paste(self):
        text = QApplication.clipboard().text()
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText(text)

    def delete(self):
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText("")

    def gotoline(self):
        self.lineWin.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
Window = writter()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: better to clarify your question.

Comment: why are you importing tkinter in a PyQt5 application? They aren't designed to work together.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating another QTextEdit within the gotolineWin widget and that is unnecessary, plus you are moving the cursor of the QTextEdit that is not the QTextEdit shown in the QMainWindow. Considering this, I have created a QDialog that should only receive the QTextEdit that adds the functionality you want.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GoToDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    gotoSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, text_edit, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.m_text_edit = text_edit

        self.spinbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(minimum=1)
        self.m_text_edit.document().blockCountChanged.connect(self.spinbox.setMaximum)
        self.spinbox.setMaximum(self.m_text_edit.document().blockCount())

        self.buttonGoto = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Go to...")
        self.buttonGoto.clicked.connect(self.onAccepted)
        self.buttonCancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.buttonCancel.clicked.connect(self.reject)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(self.buttonGoto)
        hlay.addWidget(self.buttonCancel)
        vlay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Go to..."))
        vlay.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        vlay.addLayout(hlay)
        self.setFixedSize(300, 100)

    def onAccepted(self):
        n = self.spinbox.value() - 1
        if 0 <= n < self.m_text_edit.document().blockCount():
            cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(
                self.m_text_edit.document().findBlockByLineNumber(n)
            )
            self.m_text_edit.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.reject()


class Writter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)

        self.goto_dialog = GoToDialog(self.text_edit, self)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu("Edit")

        goto_edit = QtWidgets.QAction("Go To...", self)
        goto_edit.setShortcut("Ctrl+T")
        goto_edit.triggered.connect(self.goto_dialog.show)
        editMenu.addAction(goto_edit)

        self.resize(600, 500)
        self.center()

    def center(self):
        self.setGeometry(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(
                QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight,
                QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter,
                self.size(),
                QtWidgets.qApp.desktop().availableGeometry(),
            )
        )


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Writter()
    w.show()
    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```